# "Other" Storage is what on a Lumia Icon?

Tags: lumia, storage

I am receiving an out of storage message on my Nokia Lumia Icon phone. When I check my storage I see it has 19GB of data under the `Other` category. I have no idea what this data is.

How do I find out what this data is and then remove some of it?